# Trouble understanding custom command usage

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm just starting out with WPF and I want to use custom commands whenever possible as part of the MVVM pattern. The book that I've been using (C# 2010 All-in-One for Dummies) has a sample of a custom command but it uses hard coded information to complete its task and I don't see how to use the Command system to complete *my* task.

**Book Code:**

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public string Text { get; internal set; }

    public abstract void Execute(object parameter);

    public abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}

public class AddCustomerCommand : CommandBase
{
    public AddCustomerCommand()
    {
        Text = “Add Customer”;
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var list = parameter as IList<Customer>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        list.Add(new Customer { ID = 4, Name = “New Customer”} );
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter is IList<Customer>;
    }
}
```

In this case, `Execute` works because it is passed an `IList<Customer>` and can add to it without needing to return anything. This makes perfect sense to me.

**My Problem:**

I have an MVVM app that has a data grid, some text boxes, and some buttons. My view model has `IList<Entry> Entries`, properties for the text boxes, and of course an instance of my custom command `AddEntryCommand`. The goal is to be able to enter text, and hit add, and have a new `Entry` be added to `Entries` using `AddEntryCommand`.

What I don't understand is how to go about getting `Entries` and the new data into the command. Here are the possible solutions I've thought of and what I see wrong with them

1. Pass in the view model so that all its information is available.
2. Pass in an array of objects.
3. Pass in a `Tuple`.

   - Passing thew view model seems excessive, and if I do that then everything on the view model would have to be mutable.
   - I try and avoid using `object` whenever possible, and `object[]` seems even more work to deal with. I'd have to pick it apart like command line arguments.
   - Tuples...
   - My idea of a command is that it's supposed to be a method with bells and whistles for making the UI react nicely. Anything that causes the command to be tied to a specific view or view model breaks that.

So my questions are:

**How do you do work with multiple objects using `ICommand`?**

**How can you use `ICommand` to work with immutable objects if it's locked to return `void`?**

**Is my idea of what a command is for way off base?**

(I've tried searching for a better tutorial or resource for this but my Google fu is weak and I can't seem to locate anything that's clear and concise. There are lots of questions on SO about commands in WPF, but they're all for very specific implementations. I'm looking for a general answer regarding manipulating multiple objects in one command.)

**UPDATE**

I have been looking around the net some more but I still haven't found anything like the sample provided by my book. I have looked at `DelegateCommand` and that seems like a pretty straightforward and easy to use system. It still leaves me wondering why such a large chunk of the chapter on MVVM would be dedicated to creating a custom command using just `ICommand` and not one of the other classes that already inherit from it.